# name of probability + (pseudo)random functions

Tags: naming

What is a group/family of functions that is random but some number(s) are more likely to come?
For example, calling each of this fake functions 10 times give:

- random2: 2,3,2,4,2,6,7,2,2,2
- random4: 4,1,2,3,4,4,2,1,4,9

As you can see, `random2` gives more number 2, `random4` gives more number 4.
Both functions have some patterns (not 100% random).

Comment: A "100% random" number generator *will* have some patterns in it, because a complete lack of "patterns" is itself a predictable pattern.

Comment: What is the probability distribution of these RNGs? I would usually expect a RNG to create *uniformly distributed* numbers, though I've also had cases where I needed numbers with a Gaussian distribution. Given an expected distribution, we can use the Chi-Square Test to check whether the actual distribution is OK. In your example, the sample size is to small, but if `random2` produces a lot more 2s than any other number, it would be unsuitable as an uniformly distributed RNG: We could also call it *flawed*, *broken*, or *dangerous*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In probability theory, when a random variable is more likely to produce one result than another, we call it *biased* towards the first result. I would probably call your functions *randomBiasedTo2* etc.

Comment: I don't mean how to name each function, but the group of functions. Using word "biased" I was able to find something. "Biased or weighted random number (generators)" show some results in the google, like this: http://codetheory.in/weighted-biased-random-number-generation-with-javascript-based-on-probability/